# Mysql Group by and order in descending for each group

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a sql that will group by the continent and then order the total sales for each continent in descending order in year 2000. And here is what I have done:

```
SELECT SUM(price) AS SaleSum, continent, country 
FROM  fact as F, address as A, daterecord as D 
WHERE F.address = A.id and F.transactionDate=D.id and D.`year`=2000
GROUP BY continent, country
ORDER BY SaleSum DESC
```

and it turned out that the output is only ordered in descending of the total sales, and the continent are not grouped. How can I approach to the problem? Thank you!

**Update**

The above seems to be a bit confusing. What I am expecting is a sorted results of total sales on country grouped by the continent. That is saying that for each continent, counties in that continent need to be sorted based upon the total sales. Sorry for the confusion caused.

Comment: Your where clause seems to be a bit odd... date = id, address = id? Which table does transactionDate belong to?

Comment: oh  sorry, the transactionDate belong to the fact table

Comment: And the schema I am using is the ROLAP for datawarehousing, thus the fact table are actually storing the id of other tables @jarlh

Comment: the continent is not grouped because you are grouping by continent AND country. what's your expected result?

Comment: Hi, i am actually expecting a sorted results of the total sales on the country grouped by the continent :> @fthiella

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should learn to use proper `join` syntax.  Simple rule:  never use a comma in the `from` clause.

Second, I think you just need two keys in the `order by`:

```
SELECT SUM(price) AS SaleSum, continent, country 
FROM fact F JOIN
     address A
     ON F.address = A.id JOIN
     daterecord D 
     ON F.transactionDate = D.id
WHERE D.`year`=2000
GROUP BY continent, country
ORDER BY continent, SaleSum DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you need use HAVING clause

```
SELECT SUM(price) AS SaleSum, continent, country, d.year as year
FROM  fact as F, address as A, daterecord as D 
WHERE F.address = A.id and F.transactionDate=D.id 
GROUP BY continent, country, year
HAVING year = 2000
ORDER BY SaleSum DESC
```

Comment: No improvement I suppose. HAVING is typically for conditions with aggregate functions.

Comment: Hi, I tried this and the results seems to be the same as my above query, where the continent are not grouped

Comment: Just first group by year